# Self-extracting exe for windows mobile

Tags: windows-mobile, self-extracting

Does anyone know if Windows Mobile 6 and Windows CE can open self-extracting exe without any need for third party app.

My problem is that I have application that for updating supports only exe format. Until now there hasn't been need delivering more files that only exe but I need to add new .dll to this application. So I need to pack it but can't use cab since older versions of this app don't know how to handel it.

If somebody knows how to make self-extracting exe for Windows Mobile would really appreciate it to know how to do it and what software to use for generating it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check wceload, to deliver cab files and update applications.

Answer (score 0):

You may try 7-zip: according to this page it supports sfx on windows CE http://loggencsg.googlecode.com/git-history/2e29e5a780df1c811af63ec37ace879a5f10dede/7z/Installer/readme.txt
See "Windows CE (ARM) version of 7zS2.sfx is included to 7-Zip for Windows Mobile package."

Any other approach would need you to write your own sfx exe using free 7-zip or zlib.